# TFS changes listitem's case

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I created a field with 3 allowed values:
 undefined,
 required 
 required.
Tfs changed required to Required. 
I tried to change undefined to Undefined. But it changed value to lowercase. 
Also i tried to create globallist filled with these 3 values. Result is the same. Also i tried to change XML and import it using witadmin.exe. Same thing.
Have anyone had same problem?

Answer (score 0):

TFS is case insensitive. There is no supported way to chang this, as you'd have to update the operational database to fix this. If you want to keep your warranty you'll need to contact MS support and they may provide you with a script.

Comment: Yes it is, But these are string fields which will be displayed at WI form. And it is not good if one row in a list will start with uppercase and another with lowercase.

Comment: I'm don't disagree with you, I'm just telling you that is how TFS behaves. PS: People editing through Excel will also bypass the case checking, which can cause records to be created in the DB with mixed cases.

Comment: Ok. I'l try this. Thank you!